# How can I use '<' in the value attribute of a component

Tags: jsf, facelets

When I try to name my `a4j:commandButton` by the value `<<`
Like that

```
<a4j:commandButton id="myButton" 
    value="<<"
    render="myGrid"
    styleClass="style_btn"
    disabled="false" />
```

There is an error occure

My debugging  trace

```
Error Traced[line: 88] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.] with root cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /screens/s1.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 88] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:390)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:364)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [XML/HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) to insert `<` or `>` in an XML file :

```
value="&lt;&lt;"
```

Comment: work well .. but why using '<<' is not accepted ?