# how to display symbol < and > using <p:outputlable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am new to primefaces and i am getting error  **Error Parsing /pages/1.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 134] The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.** anyone know how will be set < and > symbols?

```
<p:outputLabel value="< 10 min" />
<p:outputLabel value="> 10 min" />
```

Comment: Next time please post (parts of) the exception in a search engine first. There are about a million articles on there about this error. With literally your error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707815/how-i-can-name-my-button-by-the-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape them with

```
<p:outputLabel value="&lt; 10 min" />
<p:outputLabel value="&gt; 10 min" />
```